# How to understand a role of a queue in a distributed system?

Tags: message-queue, distributed-system

I am trying to understand what is the use case of a **queue** in distributed system.
And also how it scales and how it makes sure it's not a single point of failure in the system?

Any direct answer or a reference to a document is appreciated.

1. Use case:
   I understand that queue is a messaging system. And it decouples the systems that communicate between each other. But, is that the only point of using a queue?
2. Scalability:
   How does the queue scale for high volumes of data? Both read and write.
3. Reliability:
   How does the queue not becoming a single point of failure in the system? Does the queue do a replication, similar to data-storage?

My question is not specified to any particular queue server like Kafka or JMS. Just in general.

Answer (score 1):

my take:

1. I would be careful with "decouple" term - if service A calls api on service B, there is coupling since there is a contract between services; this is true even if the communication is happening over a queue, file or fax. The key with queues is that the communication between services is asynchronous. Which means their runtimes are decoupled - from practical point of view, either of systems may go down without affecting the other.
2. Queues can scale for large volumes of data by partitioning. From clients point of view, there is one queue, but in reality there are many queues/shards and number of shards helps to support more data. Of course sharding a queue is not "free" - you will lose global ordering of events, which may need to be addressed in you application.
3. A good queue based solution is reliable based on replication/consensus/etc - depends on set of desired properties. Queues are not very different from databases in this regard.

To give you more direction to dig into:

- there an interesting feature of queues: deliver-exactly-once, deliver-at-most-once, etc
- may I recommend Enterprise Architecture Patterns - https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Messaging.html this is a good "system design" level of information
- queues may participate in distributed transactions, e.g. you could build something like delete a record from database and write it into queue, and that will be either done/committed or rolledback - another interesting topic to explore

Answer (score 0):

### Queue is a mental concept, the implementation decides about 1 + 2 + 3

**A1:** No, it is not the only role -- a messaging seems to be main one, but a distributed-system signalling is another one, by no means any less important. Hoare's seminal CSP-paper is a flagship in this field. Recent decades gave many more options and "smart-behaviours" to work with in designing a distributed-system signalling / messaging services' infrastructures.

**A2:** Scaling envelopes depend a lot on implementation. It seems obvious that a broker-less queues can work way faster, that a centralised, broker-based, infrastructure. Transport-classes and transport-links account for additional latency + performance degradation as the data-flow volumes grow. BLOB-handling is another level of a performance cliff, as the inefficiencies are accumulating down the distributed processing chain. Zero-copy ( almost ) zero-latency smart-Queue implementations are still victims of the operating systems and similar resources limitations.

**A3:** Oh sure it is, if left on its own, the SPOF. However, Theoretical Cybernetics makes us safe, as we can create reliable systems, while still using error-prone components. ( M + N )-failure-resilient schemes are thus achievable, however the budget + creativity + design-discipline is the ceiling any such Project has to survive with.